# Resize bitmap image to make 100x100 profile picture?

Tags: android, image, bitmap

Hi so I need a user to be able to upload a profile picture that I have to re-size and put in their profile. The "area" for the profile picture is a 100x100 square since its on an android device. Lets assum someone posted a 300 x 600 or 600 x 300 how would I convert / crop an image to fit a 100 x 100 square and look good as a profile image? I feel like this is more of a conventional question.

I do know how to resize and crop bitmaps just can't figure out how would I go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for instance

android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true);

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are not against wasting some of the space, I recommend just doing basic scaling. Divide the larger size by 100 gives the scale factor. Then divide by that on each dimension and you have a picture with the right aspect ratio that fits your area.